# How to add package to graalpython known packges list?

Tags: python, graalpython

`graalpython -m ginstall install --help` will list packages known to [graalpython](https://www.graalvm.org/python/):

```
Known packages are pytest, pytest_parallel, py, attrs, pyparsing, packaging, more_itertools, atomicwrites, pluggy, zipp, wcwidth, PyYAML, six, Cython, setuptools, pkgconfig, wheel, protobuf,
Keras_preprocessing, gast, astor, absl_py, mock, Markdown, Werkzeug, h5py, sortedcontainers, hypothesis, setuptools_scm, numpy, dateutil, certifi, idna, chardet, urllib3, requests, lightfm, pytz, pandas, scipy,
cycler, cppy, cassowary, Pillow, matplotlib
```

How to add new packages to that list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The list is basically hardcoded in the script.

https://github.com/oracle/graalpython/commit/ffbeafec0387d22491b9c2ca088ad10543d1de61

> ginstall is defined here: https://github.com/oracle/graalpython/blob/master/graalpython/lib-graalpython/modules/ginstall.py

Taken from https://github.com/oracle/graalpython/issues/230#issuecomment-882343669